# Can summon spells be used to summon the same specific creatures repeatedly?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, summoning

Can one use a *summon monster* spell to summon each time Bob the Celestial Monkey specifically, or must the summoned celestial monkey be a different celestial monkey each time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The summoned creatures are always different specific creatures *unless* the DM is using a variant that alters the standard *summon* spells

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Variant: Summoning Individual Monsters says that

> When a character casts a *summon monster* or *summon nature’s ally* spell, she gets a typical, random creature of the kind she chooses. As a variant in your campaign, you can rule that each spellcaster gets specific, individual creatures rather than just some random one. This variant lets players feel more ownership over the creatures that their characters summon, but it entails some special problems, so don’t allow it without considering it carefully. (37)

The text then devotes another **500 words** to this variant, the reproduction of all of which probably breaks some laws. Suffice it to say, it's complicated, but it has the advantage of being *officially* optional if that's a meaningful bar for your group.

Answer (score 15):

### Technically, no.

Summon Monster allows you to choose which kind of creature, not the specific member of that kind. Lesser Planar Ally, however, does.

---

[Summon Monster](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/summonMonsterI.htm) states:

> You choose which ***kind*** of creature to summon, and you can change that choice each time you cast the spell.

[Lesser Planar Ally](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planarAllyLesser.htm) states:

> If you know an individual creature’s name, you may request ***that individual*** by speaking the name during the spell (though you might get a different creature anyway).

---

**What's the difference?**

[Conjuration (Summoning)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#summoning) vs. [Conjuration (Calling)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#calling). Summoning is random. Calling is not-so-random.

---

**In the Spirit of Roleplaying**

Would it be unreasonable for a DM to allow you to summon the same creature over and over? Probably not so unreasonable; however, that creature may get tired of being summoned by the same person over and over without being tributed in some fashion.

One thing you wouldn't want your summoned creature to think is:

[image: Angry Cat]

Comment: Is the summoned creature actually _removed_ from its plane? I'm kind-of remembering reading somewhere that you were basically summoning a simulacrum of that creature, not the actual creature itself.

Comment: @Lohoris The *Player's Handbook* doesn't say that. What it says: "A summoned creature also goes away if it is killed or if its hit points drop to 0 or lower. It is not really dead. It takes 24 hours for the creature to reform, during which time it can’t be summoned again" (173). However, what you're remembering is traditionally the way that text's rationalized.

Comment: Given my groups habits of abusing poor summoned creatures (dropping horses off cliffs to kill giants, for example), I'd hate to think it was the same creature each time...